# Can't open physical disk device in macOS 10.13

Tags: macos, low-level, block-device

I'm developing some low-level system tools that need to read the physical storage device. Prior to macOS 10.13, I was able to open `/dev/disk0`, `/dev/disk1`, etc. and read raw data from the device.  But after upgrading, I'm no longer able to open these devices, and I get "Operation not permitted" errors, even though I'm running as sudo.  Is there a way to access the physical drive in this version?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question.  It's more of a sysadmin question about device permissions (and maybe access controls other than Unix mode bits).  Try asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com/.  In your question there, include `ls -l` output for `/dev/disk0`, and dump the ACLs if possible.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. I'll migrate to Apple SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macos10.13, must disable the SIP to access the disk0.

1.boot into recovery

2.execute cmdline: csrutil disable

ref: https://www.easeus.com/mac-data-recovery-software/data-recovery-from-system-disk-under-new-macos.html